# I want a curriculum to study computer science

Tags: computer-science

We are a group of students want to study computer science "self-learning"
We want a curriculum to be followed so that there are 4 subjects per year for 4 years
Can anyone help us develop a specific curriculum?
Or even the names of the material + if the names of the books provide
thank you 
this is the first question for me
i wish that i post it in the right place
Sorry for my bad language

Comment: I forgot to tell you that we are studying in electrical department
If so, let me tell you the names of the items that we are studying in the section

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are some suggestions you might find helpful. Notice that many of these courses are not in computer science, per se, but are intended to provide the required mathematical background, and develop the required mathematical maturity, to really master the material in upper-level courses in computer science.

If you were to study eight courses for eight years, I'd have at least four times as many math courses and, at that level, likely more than that.

Fall, Year 1

- Calculus I: limits, derivative, antiderivative, integration, fundamental theorem
- Programming I: variables, control structures, iteration, recursion

Spring, Year 1

- Calculus II: applications & methods of integration, sequences & series
- Programming II: data structures, OOP, reference vs value

Fall, Year 2

- Calculus III: vectors, gradient, line integrals
- Discrete Math: truth tables, pigeonhole principles, combinations, permutations, proofs

Spring, Year 2

- Linear Algebra: systems of equations, vector spaces, eigenvalues and eigenvectors
- Programming Languages and Paradigms: OOP, functional, logical, procedural, BNF

Fall, Year 3

- Probability and Statistics I: order statistics, mean, standard deviation, conditional probability, Bayesian
- Algorithms & Data Structures: searching, sorting, graphs, dynamic programming, complexity

Spring, Year 3

- Probability and Statistics II: simulation, queuing, stochastic processes
- Computer Operating Systems: file system, scheduling, caching, permissions

Fall, Year 4

- Formal Languages and Automata: finite automata, pushdown automata, Turing machines
- Computer Architecture and Assembly Languages: instruction set, pipelined CPU, parallelism, RAM

Spring, Year 4

- Software Engineering: process models, estimation, quality assurance, modeling
- Computer Networks: OSI protocol layers, UDP, TCP, HTTP

Comment: Thank you so much
We are studying the Electrical Engineering Department in the Communications Division and will study 8 math courses

Comment: The file containing the subject has been lost
I try to bring it